# Bad Notation? Using the infinity symbol with inequality signs.

Tags: inequality, notation, infinity

I am a teacher and I teach my students that using the infinity symbol as pictured here is bad.  Students learn set notation along side interval notation, and when translating directly between the two, often times what should be written $x<2$ becomes $-\infty<x<2$. Now I have discovered that the textbook my county adopted uses the notation the way I instruct my students NOT to, and I am looking for confirmation that I have not been misleading my students. Please take a side - I say NEVER put an infinity sign in an inequality expression!  Wrong or right?  Gray area?  TIA. The following is from the textbook:

> What is the domain of $x=-9y^2$?
>
> A.  $-\infty<x\leq-3$
>
> B.  $-\infty<x\leq0$
>
> C.  $-\infty<x<\infty$
>
> D.  $0\leq x<\infty$

Comment: I don't think any reasonable person would be confused by either choice.  Not everything has to be done in only one way.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In the context of [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) it's okay

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with it as long as you clarify that $\infty$ is not a (real) and here is just a symbol. I do agree that the infinities in these examples are quite excessive though, but I suppose it could be there to prepare the students for interval notation, like for example $[0,\infty)$. Furthermore, infinites are quite commonly used like where quantites can be infinite. For example, it is quite common to write $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j<\infty$ for a convergent series of non-negative numbers.

Comment: Often such inequalities appear as $a\le x\le b$ for real numbers $a,b$. Then, since $\pm \infty$ are not real numbers, you can NEVER write options A.-D., i.e., using $a=-\infty$ or $b=\infty$. On the other hand, $0<\sum_{n\ge 1} 1/n^2<\infty$ is indeed used very often.

Comment: I have no idea why this question has 4 votes to close. I think it's a perfectly reasonable question and it's reasonable to be confused about this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the votes to close are because it's phrased in a way that is seeking opinions, which is a valid close reason on SE even when the question is otherwise perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "right" or "wrong" here. This is a matter of convention and I think either convention is okay. The comments make good points that this is not so different from using $\infty$ in interval notation such as $[0, \infty)$ (which is fairly standard as far as I know) and also that it's consistent with the common notation $\sum a_i < \infty$ used to mean that a series converges (which is also fairly common as far as I know, and is used e.g. to specify that functions have bounded norm and stuff like that, in expressions like $\int |f(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty$).

However, for this *specific* question about domains I personally think this notation has the potential to be confusing for students and should be avoided. The reason is that writing a strict inequality $-\infty < x < \infty$ suggests the question: why not allow a weak inequality $-\infty \le x \le \infty$ into the notation? And then: if we allow $x$ to take the values $\pm \infty$ then why not allow $y$ to take these values? And then: should we say that e.g. $0$ is in the domain of $y = \frac{1}{x}$ because $y$ can take the value $\infty$ there? In other words, as Dietrich says in the comments, this notation invites confusion about whether $\infty$ is being treated as a real number, which makes the whole concept of domain ambiguous.

The interval notation $[0, \infty)$ also invites this confusion, admittedly, but it's very convenient and meanwhile in this context, as you say, the $\infty$s can be dropped entirely. The options could just be rewritten

1. $x \le -3$
2. $x \le 0$
3. All $x$
4. $0 \le x$